# Linked Server Connection Issue to SQL Server AlwaysOn Listener

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, linked-server, oledb

I have SQL Server 2008R2 Standard Edition. I am making a Linked Server connection to a Listener of an AlwaysOn Availability Group.

However, when I run a query from SSMS I intermittently get this error:

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Listener,4600" returned message "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Listener,4600".

I thought it may be a driver issue but OLE DB looks to be installed.

Any idea what I may be missing?

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the default connection timeout value.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8c87fb8-2ef2-429f-af52-20e9e0074357/changing-default-connection-timeout-value-for-sql-connection?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: The issue is from within SSMS rather than through application code

Comment: You are connecting to a different server using a linked server connection.